# Adding Paging to PHP/mySQL list

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a php/mysql list, where I can display lots of thumbnails.

My problem is that there are too many images to display in one page. I would like to divide it so that I can get some page links or something at the bottom?

Like: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or next and prev...

Here is the current code:

```
<?php
    if ($db_found) {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);

        while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<div class="thumb"><img src="images/thumbnails/'.$db_field['image'].'" alt="" /></a></div>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        mysql_close($db_handle);
    }
?>
```

How can I add some page links here?

Comment: Please tag your questions appropriately - this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: [http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html] for php pagination

[http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-jquery-pagination-system/] jquery pagination

Comment: this is a [code](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html) of php pagination

Comment: @jugnu link is dead? :o **edit** n/m your ] gets added with url ;P

Comment: Use mysql offset and limit in the query to get a set amount of results. Then display them and use the offset to calculate what page you are on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's much more easy with Jquery but i Recommends you to work with PHP for start,
It can only develop your head than to add some JQuery code will get you everything.
anyway simple paging with PHP goes like that,
the key's for learning this code is to understand:
intval,LIMIT,mysql_num_rows,mysql_fetch_assoc,mysql_fetch_row,ceil,COUNT
after you will learn each off them the code will be much easy to understand and you can develop it and add some of your own Improvements.
The Credit for this Excellent site : [PHPGuide](http://phpguide.co.il/index.php)

```
 $per_page = 5; 
 $page = 1;

 if (isset($_GET['page'])) 
 {
  $page = intval($_GET['page']); 
  if($page < 1) $page = 1;
}


 $start_from = ($page - 1) * $per_page; 

 mysql_connect(..);
 mysql_select_db(..);

 $current_items = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `test` LIMIT $start_from, $per_page");
 if( mysql_num_rows($current_items) > 0)
 {
  while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($current_items))
  {
    echo $item['text'], '<br/>';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'this page does not exists'; 
 }


 $total_rows = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`");
 $total_rows = mysql_fetch_row($total_rows);
 $total_rows = $total_rows[0];

 $total_pages = $total_rows / $per_page;
 $total_pages = ceil($total_pages); # 19/5 = 3.8 ~=~ 4

 for($i = 1; $i  <= $total_pages; ++$i)
 {
  echo "<a href='?page=$i'>$i</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;";
 }
```

The Code is Very Easy to understand and very simple. 
and about the prev and forward page it's one of the improvements you will do after you get this code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $per_page = 20;
    $start=0; 

    if(isset($_GET['pagenum']))
      {
      $pagenum=$_GET['pagenum'];
      $start=($pagenum*$per_page)
      }
    if ($db_found) {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable  Limit $start , $per_page";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $pages = ceil($count/$per_page)
        while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<div class="thumb"><img src="images/thumbnails/'.$db_field['image'].'" alt="" /></a></div>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        mysql_close($db_handle);
    }

    //Create you links here 
    for($pagenum=1; $pagenum<=$pages; $pagenum++)
    {
     echo '<a href="'.$pagenum.'">'.$pagenum.'</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You added page numbers but are still showing all of the images.

Comment: `LIMIT` is `LIMIT start_offset, number`, not `LIMIT start_offset,end_offset`

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your query and give it the parameter,

in this line:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
```

use something like this

```
jcho360> select * from actor limit 0,5;
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name    | last_update         |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|        1 | PENELOPE   | GUINESS      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        2 | NICK       | WAHLBERG     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        3 | ED         | CHASE        | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        4 | JENNIFER   | DAVIS        | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        5 | JOHNNY     | LOLLOBRIGIDA | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

jcho360> select * from actor limit 5,5;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|        6 | BETTE      | NICHOLSON | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        7 | GRACE      | MOSTEL    | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        8 | MATTHEW    | JOHANSSON | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        9 | JOE        | SWANK     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       10 | CHRISTIAN  | GABLE     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

jcho360> select * from actor limit 10,5;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|       11 | ZERO       | CAGE      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       12 | KARL       | BERRY     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       13 | UMA        | WOOD      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       14 | VIVIEN     | BERGEN    | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       15 | CUBA       | OLIVIER   | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |

+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

so when you click next/back you give the parameter to the query, and you'll have your pagination

Answer (score 1):

1. run a COUNT query to determine how many thumbs there are in your db
2. Calculate the number of pages:

   ```
   $pageCount = ceil($numberOfThumbs / $thumbsPerPage)
   ```
3. create one link per page containing the page number
4. calculate the offset:

   ```
   $offset = ($page-1)*$thumbsPerPage
   ```
5. add `limit` to your query:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT $offset, $thumbsPerPage
   ```

http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can use PEAR's  [Pager](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.pager.intro.php) class?

1) Download the module from http://pear.php.net/package/Pager/download or execute the following command at the command prompt.

```
c:\pear install Pager
```

2) Copy the above to your PEAR includes directory which preferably is "c:\your php installation directory\Pear"

3) Now to look at some actual code -

```
require_once 'Pager/Pager.php';
/* We will bypass the database connection code ... */
$sqlQuery = "SOME SQL QUERY";
$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery);
$totalRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

$pager_options = array(
'mode'       => 'Sliding',
'perPage'    => 10,
'delta'      => 4,
'totalItems' => $totalRows,
);
$pager = Pager::factory($pager_options);
echo $pager->links;
```

Comment: this is even worse then link provided by @khaled_webdev  ... his was just outdate. This one is actively bad and written for php4.

Comment: I've used this in one of my applications (that uses PHP 5) and till date it is working fine. Are there security-vulnerabilities associated with it? If so, I will have to work on removing that code and writing my own code for pagination :-)

Comment: How about the fact , that it requires you to provide it with full list of data to actually work.

Comment: Well. Yeah. but after all the application i was working on at that time had a very small dataset. But I do agree I need to revamp and work on that code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using SQL's [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause to limit the number of records returned from the query. Then increase the offset parameter in LIMIT with each page.

In PHP you'll need to generating your page links and append a query string which tells PHP which page is being requested. Multiply this value by the number of records per page to give you the offset value for the LIMIT clause.

The downside to LIMITing the number of results coming out of your MySQL query is that you will need to run a query *without* LIMIT to get a count of the total number of records so you can calculate how many page links you need to generate in PHP.

You need to consider how you want the page links formatted. Do you want simple previous|next links or a more complicated first|previous|n|n|n|n|next|last. From a user point of view I always feel that being able to skip to first/last pages and to particular page numbers is useful but it depends on what you need really.

There's probably extensions/classes out there that do this all for you automatically but I'm a roll-your-own guy when it comes to building SQL queries.